# Error on foreign key

Tags: magento-1.9, error, entities, foreign-key

I have added a `product_id` column in my table `vaibhav_customtabs_product_entity`. Now I am trying to add foreign key on `product_id` from `catalog_product_entity`->`entity_id` column, but it is throwing error.
Below is my code for add foreign key.

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addForeignKey(
 $installer->getFkName('vaibhav_customtabs/product_entity', 'product_id', 'catalog/product','entity_id'),
 'product_id',
 $installer->getTable('catalog/product'), 
 'entity_id',
 Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, 
 Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

> Error

```
Error in file: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store1/app/code/local/Vaibhav/Customtabs/sql/vaibhav_customtabs_setup/upgrade-1.0.0.1-1.0.0.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'store1.product_id' doesn't exist
```

Do I have to add foreign key or alter the column `product_id` with foreign key as I have already created the column.

Comment: Post your module config file code here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('vaibhav_customtabs_product_entity', 'product_id', 'catalog_product_entity','entity_id'),
        $installer->getTable('vaibhav_customtabs_product_entity'),
        $installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'), 
        'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, 
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )  
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```